# Embed latest youtube upload on webpage

Tags: html, wordpress, youtube

I have tried finding documentation on how to do this but I just couldn't find any, all the ways I tried where all using or the old api or just displayed nothing, the ideal format that I wanted is using this generator: http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube.html I got this working on the site but when I copied the code to my own site (running wordpress, I also tried it just in a blank file). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using that code, use the official Google's Youtube Data API to integration youtube lists into your website.

Link to Youtube Data API search lists: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#http-request

Comment: Thanks for your help!